# MAX134 and MAX3001E Troubleshooting

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, pcb-design, level-shifting, testbench

This is going to be a long question because I plan to include a lot of context that I feel is important to grasp the full scope of my issue.

I am currently a senior year university student hard at work designing PCBs for my senior design project. My group and I have settled on designing a multimeter from scratch.

After doing some component analysis and research, we have landed on the Maxim Integrated MAX134 Digital Multimeter IC for our data acquisition chip. Part of the requirement for our project included incorporating a Cypress programmable system on a chip (PSoC), specifically the Cypress PSoC 63 BLE module (CYBLE-416045-02) for our microprocessor.

Since the DMM circuit runs off of +/-5V supplies, and the logic level of our PSoC is strictly 3.3V, we needed to include level-shifters between our DMM circuit and our PSoC. For this we used the Maxim Integrated MAX3001E 8-channel level shifter, as well as another 4-channel one by a similar name.

I should note that much of the design decisions I made for the DMM circuit application was taken from the MAX134 Evaluation Board Schematic and Datasheet, which I will link below, along with the MAX134 chip datasheet.

We got the boards fabbed and assembled them ourselves to begin verifying the integrity of the circuits. We put the PSoC and DMM circuit each on their own individual breakout boards, using jumper wires to connect the two for testing purposes.

Now I will begin explaining the core of the issue. To limit as many variables as possible, we started by simply connecting power to only the DMM board on it's own using a programmable power supply to measure the power draw of the board as well as make sure that all data that would be leaving the board would be properly voltage-translated.

One of the things that caught my eye is the current draw of the system was upwards of 80mA, which corresponds to almost 0.8W. Specifically, the 5V source was drawing about 70mA, and the -5V source was drawing 10mA. The 3.3V source was only drawing about 1mA, which is what I would expect, considering it was only powering the level shifters. The DMM circuit power draw seemed particularly high, and after measuring the temperature of each of the IC's with my finger, it was clear that the MAX134 chip was consuming most of the power.

We measured the voltage coming to the breakout pins from the output of the level shifters, and they were a very clean 3.3V. However, the logic coming from the MAX134 chip seemed to be in some sort of voltage-reduced state, all of the data pins outputting a voltage between 3.7 and 4.1 volts.

Next I wanted to measure the voltage reaching the MAX134 from the pins. On the address logic headers, I supplied `0b101` to the board. This voltage reached the level shifters just fine, but after being shifted to the new level, it was once again reduced to around 3.7 to 3.3 volts, with the logic low state measuring around 0.5 volts.

This is the crux of my issue really. I'm unsure whether to hook up my microprocessor board to try to communicate with the MAX134 chip, when it seems that either the level shifters or the MAX134 chip itself seem to be having issues. I was looking at the data sheet for the MAX3001E chip, and supposedly receiving these voltages after translation is "within threshold" but it realistically it could be below the threshold for the MAX134 chip to recognize. This could also be a power-supply issue as well, or perhaps a board assembly issue since it was hand-assembled using solder paste, possibly leading to a short somewhere (but continuity checks seem to debunk this possibility).

All of this, not even to mention the fact that it seems that no matter what control register address I attempt to index in the MAX134 returns anything other than `0b1111` in the data lines.

Has anyone had logic level shifting issues in the past? Could it be an error in assembly or design?

Any and all help is appreciated. If you would like to see my schematic or PCB document, I am happy to share.

---

Level shifter data sheet: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3000E-MAX3012.pdf

MAX134 chip data sheet: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX133-MAX134.pdf

MAX134 Evaluation Board Datasheet:
https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX134EVKIT.pdf

---

***EDIT***

All boards were designed using Altium Designer.

Screenshot of Board Layout Document (MAX134 in orange, level shifters in blue, bandgap reference in red, external AC to RMS converter in green. 5 IC's in total):
[image: Board Layout Document]

Screenshot of Schematic Document:

[image: Board Schematic Document]

Comment: Step 1: beep connections and make sure pinout is OK. Step 2: scope the power line of the chip. Step 3: try to replace the chip (if possible). Also, I take it the negative rail of MAX134 is -5V and its output may be referenced not to GND but to -5V. Did you take that into account?

Comment: This sounds as if the 5 V supply is shorted to the 3.3 V supply. Anyway, show the schematic.

Comment: Can you please show your board’s schematic? The symptoms you describe sound as if the max134 interface bus isn’t being enabled. I’m familiar with both the max134 and the max300x level translators, but there may be some subtle detail in how they are connected. The logic levels should be much closer to the power supply rails; that’s related to higher than normal supply current.

Comment: Did you build a prototype before sending the board design out for fab? That would usually be part of the design process for a capstone design course, and it would help tell you whether the problem is in the overall design or in the PCB.

Comment: @Ilya -- I'll try scoping the power line of the chip on monday when I'm back in the lab, but the power supply seemed to have fairly stagnant current and voltage, not much flakiness in the connection either. Also tried re-soldering the powe supply headers early on, but no avail. As per the datasheet, the output logic is taken in reference to DGND, which in our schematics' case is ground. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson -- unfortunately due to COVID in my senior year, a lot of the capstone project schedule has been in limbo, and as a result many other groups decided upon easier design projects. I still have confidence in my ability to complete this project, though there are less than 4 weeks left in the quarter. We originally planned to order the evaluation board as a reference, but unfortunately it is obsolete and non-stock from every reputable distributor.

Comment: @MarkU -- just updated the question to include screenshots of both the schematic document and the board layout. The board was designed in Altium Designer.

Comment: One common issue with those bi-directional level shifters is that the pins really, really should not be left floating. If the impedance is more than 6000 ohms, it won't register as being driven. So use something like a 4.7k ohm resistor to logic low or logic high, to ensure that the level translator has valid logic levels.

Comment: @MarkU I probably wouldn't have left the two leftover 5V-side level shifter pins floating, but the schematic document from the MAX134 evaluation kit clearly indicated to do so. Does grounding the 3.3V side of those lanes achieve the same end, or do we need to ground both sides to ensure nothing is left floating? Because this would definitely explain the main issue that we are facing...

Comment: @MarkU I did a little more testing earlier today (as best as I could do without a proper power supply), and I tried polling voltages through the address lanes (0b000, 0b001, 0b010, etc.) and I found that the voltage of one of the pins would influence the others. If they were all logic low, then they would all read around 0.5V. However, if another one of them were logic high, the other two would shoot up to around 1.2V and stick around there until they all went low again. Would floating shifter pins cause this issue on the bus?

Comment: @MarkU The output drivers on both sides of the MAX3001E are always active, so leaving pins open is OK (they will never float). Furthermore, due to the high output impedance of about 6 kΩ, pull-up/-down resistors will form a voltage divider and result in an invalid voltage.

Comment: @CL. Also, keep in mind that the logic on the 3.3V side are completely reasonable, only the 5V side seems to have this signal issue. Could there be something wrong with the internals of the MAX134? Maybe there's some way to quickly check?

Comment: @MarkU I discovered something this morning -- the RD* pin reads perfectly into the MAX134, high or low voltage. But the WR* and A0-A2 seem to all be dependent on each other. Since all of these signals come from the same level shifter, I think this rules out the MAX3001E. Could it be the MAX134 chip itself?

Comment: The level shifters cannot drive large capacitive loads, so the connectors might become a problem. Anyway, check the 5 V supply on all chips, and that all digital inputs have a valid voltage level.

Comment: @MarkU does the pinout for my MAX134 chip seem right? I'm finding out that the documentation for the pinout for the 44 MQFP package has conflicting sources compared to both the datasheet and the ECAD model that I used from the Maxim website.

Comment: The 44MQFP pin configuration shown in the datasheet page 19 is consistent with the die photo shown on page 20, so I think the datasheet is correct. (Bond wires can't cross inside the IC package). But the MQFP the pin 1 is in the middle of a row, not the corner. So if you look at Y1, which should connect to OSC1 and OSC2, those were incorrectly positioned on your PCB layout.  Also, I notice the DGNDOUT was left unconnected; that pin should be connected to DGND on the MAX134. (*Full disclosure: I work at Maxim Integrated/Analog Devices, and worked on the previous MAX134 EV system*)

Comment: Good chance you can salvage your PCB placement by rotating the MAX134 about 45 degrees and fixing the error in the CAD layout database. I don't know what it's called in your CAD layout tool, but usually there's something that maps pin numbers to physical pads on the board. Did you create the MAX134 gate/decal/part yourself, or was is downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: @MarkU I downloaded the MAX134 landing pattern + symbol from the Maxim Website, which linked to an UltraLibrarian part. I've also been working with Maxim Technical Support, and I have found other evidence online to lead me to expect the datasheet has incorrect pinout information. Take a look at this multimeter datasheet I found on a forum that uses the exact same part and package: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/765690853263409202/943658335578767410/protek_hung_chang_506_dmm_sch_2.jpg)

Comment: @MarkU furthermore, there's a Maxim Support ticket that seems to have the exact same information as that image for the pinout information, once again totally different from the data sheet. I've since ordered a new board with the linked pinout, as well as some additional edits for further debugging. [link](https://maximsupport.microsoftcrmportals.com/en-us/knowledgebase/article/000097933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering, I found a solution to my issue. Indeed, the package information on the datasheet is wrong. The correct pin layout, quizzically, is only explicitly described on a Maxim Integrated technical forum post posted in my last comment. All in all, ADI/Maxim needs to get their datasheets reviewed, as my group and I are very unlikely to complete our project before the quarter is over at this rate due to this obvious issue.